# Retracting $\mathbb{R}^3$ minus a circle and a line to the torus.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homotopy-theory, retraction

Suppose we have a circle and a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The line lies inside the circle without intersecting it. Consider the space $X$ obtained from $\mathbb{R}^3$ minus this line and this circle. I know this space should retract to a torus $S^1 \times S^1.$

What I think is the following.

If I take a plane where the line lies on, this plane intersects the circle in two points.

The intersection of this plane with $X$ should be $\mathbb{R}^2$ minus three points. This work for any of the infinite planes where the line lies on.

So the idea would be to find a retraction onto some intersection of the torus with a plane for every such plane and then glueing those together.

> Is it possible to conclude with this line of reasoning?

Comment: If the line lies on this plane, then the intersection of the plane with $X$ should be $\mathbb{R}^2$ minus two points and the line.

Comment: By stereographic projection, $X$ is homeomorphic to $S^3$ less two interlocking circles.

Comment: Actually an easier way would be to regard $\Bbb{R}^3\setminus(\text{a line}\cup S^1)$ as $\{\text{a punctured plane}\}\times S^1$. Now, do you see the deformation retraction?